# Configuring JTA in Tomcat7

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am using JEE5 with Postgresql, When I try to persist the object the output says

> Could not find datasource: java:jdbc/postgres
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: the name jdbc/postgres is not
>   asociated with this context

In context.xml (Tomcat7) I have

```
<Context>  
  <Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5433/peopledb"
            username="postgres" password="password" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
            maxWait="-1"/>
</Context>
```

In persistence.xml I have:

```
<persistence-unit name="People">    

    <jta-data-source>java:jdbc/postgres</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
           <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
           <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

In my persistence bean I have

```
@Stateless
public class PeopleDAOImpl implements PeopleDAO {
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("People");

  @Override
  public void persistPeople(People pep) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.persist(pep);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat names the context resources differently than Glassfish. You defined the name in `context.xml` as `jdbc/postgres`, but in the `persistence.xml` you have to use `java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution and now it says  **aused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: The chosen transaction strategy requires access to the JTA TransactionManager**

Comment: You might be confusing JTA and JPA. If you really need JTA, maybe you should look into using TomEE. If you just want Hibernate JPA, then switch from a `jta-data-source` tag to a `non-jta-data-source` tag.

Answer (score 0):

A late reply, but maybe still useful for others:

JTA can be used in Tomcat with componentized implementations like Atomikos (https://www.atomikos.com).

Cheers

PS: if you want help in setting things up you may want to consider a free trial of Atomikos - which includes Tomcat support / setup.